# Recommended Server specs for multi developer VM - Sitecore 9 development

Tags: sitecore-commerce, installation, best-practices

Our company have a team (14 developers) working in a Sitecore based solution. Currently for every dev we have i7 16gb ram 500gb SSD installation in each dev machine.

But now we want to move to a server based solution where we setup 14 VM (windows server 2016) for developers. It is because so that developer can use his/her VM from outside office and also some of the machines have aged.

The primary thing we need to know what would be the recommended hardware specs for such setup. Recommended processor, ram and storage specs I mean. Is one server setup would be enough or not... things like this.

Comment: I’m not sure about server specifications, but you should thing for a backup. So I don’t thing one server will be enough. What do you think about cloud VMs with proper schedule for shutdown? I mean it could be cheaper in long term or may be not, just guessing :)

Comment: You could consider something like Amazon workspaces for this. That's what we are using currently (although I also use local VMs because it's quicker and I can manage them myself). Specs we have are:
* Intel Xeon E5 @2.3GHz
* Windows Server 2016 62 bit
* 16GB RAM
Amazon workspaces are a bit slow to backup and restore, however. I like my local VMs where I can break it and restore from backup on external SSD within a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I worked for a company 4 years ago that required developers to work on a VM in such a way as you describe.  Even though it was hosted on a good spec server for that time, the performance was significantly worse than just using a local machine due to latency. Additionally BSOD were frequent. It also made multi monitor support somewhat painful. I would recommend that you instead purchase laptops so the developers can work remotely.

As for your question about specs, these days I would recommend

- 4 or 6 core on latest generation processor
- 16GB RAM - 32GB preferred
- 500GB SSD